How to call an async method from a sync method within a larger async method
As said I want to call an async method from a sync method, the problem is the sync method is being called by another async method  so roughly something like this...
async def parent_async()
    sync_method()

def sync_method():
    #call utility_async_method

I can't just call asyncio.run since I'm already in an event loop in this case.  The obvious answer would be to just turn my sync_method into an async method, but I don't want to do that for two key reasons.

the sync_method I'm writing is overriding a method in a parent class.  The parent method is called all over the place so trying to make it async would require a major refactoring effort
sync_method is called by third party tools.  I can't make those third party tools asynchronous.

I'm okay with sync_method blocking briefly while the async method is called, I just need to figure out how to call it.

check the package  nest-asyncio

Can you use await asyncio.to_thread(sync_method) ? To clarify your question, could you also please create minimal runnable example? See [mcve] for more information

@Bindestrich That package did exactly what I needed thank you.  If you added that as an answer I'd be happy to select it so you get some points.

The package nest-asyncio is for this exact use case. It allows nested use of asyncio.run and loop.run_until_complete
simply put
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

Before your script.
I often use it in Jupyter notebooks.
